# Git: list all tracked files

Tags: git

is there a possibility in Git to show all tracked files in a repository when I am in a Subfolder? I tried: git ls-files --> but it lists just the files in the current foder and the subfolders - but not in the folders above.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on the question linked by Kristjan but with extra arguments to match output of `ls-files`:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAD
```